# How to return dynamic XML file to use in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have 10 computers (windows 7) connected to each other via LAN. Out of which one have the Apache server installed. Other computer will have VB.net application installed which will request data from this server computer.

I thinking of using XML to transfer data between server and client computer. 
Can I request a php file from VB.net client application and in return php (from server) will create dynamic XML file each time?

And this returned XML have to be parsed by VB.net. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer to a similar question about using XElement to parse XML in VB:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906969/1539015

Note that the path to the xml in XElement.Load() can be a URI like "http://apacheserver/...".