# How to parse an XML document in VB.net without a WebBrowser control?

Tags: xml, vb.net

How can I open a URL (which is an XML page) from a button's click event, for instance, and read the contents of the XML document, without using a WebBrowser control to parse it?

Comment: can you be little more detail please ? I am not able to understand your question

Comment: Your question title contains unnecessary detail. Do you really think the answer will be different based on which event you're handling, or which language you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using `XDocument`, and LINQ, as others have suggested, there are also two other common solutions.  One is to use `XmlDocument` and XPath, and the other is to use XML serialization.  For instance, if you had the following XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
  <Book Title="Book 1">
    <Author>Author 1</Author>
    <Chapter>Chapter 1</Chapter>
    <Chapter>Chapter 2</Chapter>
  </Book>
  <Book Title="Book 2">
    <Author>Author 1</Author>
    <Chapter>Chapter 1</Chapter>
    <Chapter>Chapter 2</Chapter>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

Then you could parse it with `XmlDocument` and search through it with XPath like this (where `xml` is a string containing the above XML):

```vb
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(xml)
Dim authorOfBook1 As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Books/Book[@Title = 'Book 1']/Author").InnerText
Dim booksByAuthor1 As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Books/Book[Author = 'Author 1']")
'etc.
```

Or, you could use serialization to load the XML document by, first, defining the document structure in some classes:

```vb
Public Class Books
    <XmlElement("Book")> _
    Public Items As List(Of Book)
End Class

Public Class Book
    <XmlAttribute()> _
    Public Title As String

    <XmlElement("Author")> _
    Public Authors As List(Of String)

    <XmlElement("Chapter")> _
    Public Chapters As List(Of String)
End Class
```

And then deserialize the XML into an object of that type:

```vb
Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Books))
Using reader As StringReader = New StringReader(xml)
    Dim books As Books = CType(serializer.Deserialize(reader), Books)
    'Analyze contents in books object
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

To Parse XML, You may use the **LINQtoXML** library (.Net Framework 3.5 onwards)

for example,if you have an XML in the below format,

```
<rss>
  <report name="rpt1">
    <title>AAA</title>
    <image>some1</image>   
  </report>
  <report name="rpt2">
    <title>BBB</title>
    <image>some3333</image>   
</rss>
```

This code will parse it and get the `title`  & `url` of each `report` items.

```
Dim path As String = "pathTosomexml.xml"
Dim elm As XElement = XElement.Load(path)
If elm IsNot Nothing Then

    For Each page As var In elm.Elements("report")
        Dim title = page.Element("title").Value
        Dim url = page.Element("image").Value

    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Load it into [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), using [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358684).

This will parse the document for you so you can query it using LINQ to XML.